# Spring security not authenticate the user

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a user with username `sajjad` and password `200200`:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/hello/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/myLogin.jsp"
                         default-target-url="/pages/index.jsp"
                         login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                         authentication-failure-url="/myLogin.jsp?error=1"
                         username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="sajjad" authorities="ROLE_USER" password="200200"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

And this is `myLogin.jsp`:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method="POST">
    <label for="username">User Name:</label>
    <input id="username" name="j_username" type="text"/>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" name="j_password" type="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i enter correct `username/password` and submit the form , it displays the `failure-url` and not authenticate the user.

`web.xml`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/security-config.xml
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: @questionare What is the `CustomSimpleURLAuthenticationSuccessHandler` class?

Comment: you don't need it. Actually Soroosh Sarabadani is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have changed the username parameter and password parameter in security config.
But in form you are using the default one.
change the name of inputs in your form to "username" and "password" and check it again.